# Jenkins builds not honoring third party repositories?

Tags: maven, maven-2, jenkins, pom.xml

I'm hosting ojdbc14.jar on my network nexus instance, but only local builds seem to pass.

I have this in my pom:

```
  <repositories>
    <repository>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
        </releases>
        <id>thirdparty</id>
        <url>http://server/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
```

After completing removing ~/.m2/, a local `mvn package` will find ojdbc14.jar on nexus. My jenkins builds, conversely, consistently fail on this:

```
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal 
org.csodehaus.mojo:sql-maven-plugin:1.3:execute (sql-ddl) on project mongo-dbunit: Execution 
sql-ddl of goal org.codehaus.mojo:sql-maven-plugin:1.3:execute failed: Plugin 
org.codehaus.mojo:sql-maven-plugin:1.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact com.oracle:ojdbc14:jar:10.2.0.4.0 in central
```

Why?

```
(http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd check and make sure that the Maven settings are the same on both machines.

Jenkins by default uses the file in **$HOME/.m2/settings.xml**. It's also possible for a Jenkins job to override this default.

Answer (score 3):

Before you do anything, install `Config File Provider Plugin`

Then,

1. Go to Jenkins root page
2. Choose 'Manage Jenkins'
3. Choose 'Configuration files'
4. Choose type 'Maven settings.xml file'
5. Name it 'custom-maven-settings' and cut and paste contents of your ~/.m2/settings.xml file

Now back to your Maven2/3 job.

1. In the `Build` section click `Advanced` button
2. In the `Maven Settings Configs` drop down box choose `custom-maven-settings`

This setup works with our custom repository.

Comment: Is there no way to do this strictly in the POM? If not, maven is even more terrible than I thought.

Include *developers* but not where to resolve dependencies? You must be freaking kidding me.

Comment: @Stefan.  Do you have `<repositories>` section configured in your stand-alone environment settings.xml?  If you do, can you cut-and-paste it in your posting.  On the aside, does your build fail outside of Jenkins environment.  If it does not, then it's not Maven's fault that Jenkins has implementation problems.  BTW, Hudson, in my opinion, is a much better platform for Maven builds.

Comment: @AlexanderPogrebnyak: Seriously?  Hudson is practically dead, and stuck in sponsorship limbo, while Jenkins is extremely actively developed.  And only a few months ago they were the same project.

Comment: @Daniel. Yours and my opinions may vary.

Comment: @AlexanderPogrebnyak: I -1'd because instead of dealing with the actual Maven problem, you just proposed using a different tool.  In retrospect, that's probably a bit harsh, my apologies.  As for opinions: an opinion is fine, but it would be a lot better received if you would back up your opinion with some real facts.

Comment: @Daniel. Jenkins - Maven build is a bastard child (special project type, you can't have other build steps, etc.), Hudson - Just another build step in a freestyle build. Plus Hudson has found a sponsor in Sonatype, and when it comes to Maven I do trust these guys to do a good job.  As for my answer, I had run into a similar problem in my environment, and these steps definitely helped. Plus, I don't have an X-Ray vision to deduce OP's build environment from his posting.

Comment: @AlexanderPogrebnyak: OK, that makes more sense.  FYI, in recent versions of Jenkins, Maven is just another build step as well (although the special project type persists as an alternative).  And regardless of sponsorship, the development community around Jenkins is *much* more active, and contains Kohsuke, who is pretty much singlehandedly responsible for all the code that's in Hudson anyway.  In any case, as you point out, opinions may vary.

Comment: @AlexanderPogrebnyak: FYI: I just made a small edit to whitespace so that I could retract my downvote.  Feel free to revert the edit.

Comment: @Daniel. Regarding Jenkins Maven build step.  Last time I checked that was not the case, maybe I'll look at it again next time when Hudson stops working.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `<repositories>` section in your POM, but not a `<pluginRepositories>`.  Maven used to be a lot more sloppy about the difference between compile-time artifact dependencies and plugin dependencies, but in newer versions of Maven they're completely separate.

As others have pointed out, it might be easier to troubleshoot this by running Maven from the command line, outside of Jenkins.  Just doing a build on a different machine than the one you are typically developing on will usually bring a lot issues to light.

Here's some [documentation on the POM](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html) that may or may not be helpful.

Comment: The plugins can come from repo1, that's fine. I just need to resolve the odjbc jar from the thirdparty hosted repo.

Comment: @StefanKendall: Hmmm... so you want the plugin to come from a different place than its dependency?  I've never tried that.  You can override the dependencies of a plugin by putting a `<dependencies>` tag inside the `<plugin>` tag.

Comment: @StefanKendall: Perhaps you're running into [MNG-3384](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-3384): "Repos defined in plugin are used to download dependencies".  Which version of Maven are you using?  This behavior is (ostensibly) fixed in Maven 3, which cleaned up a lot of longstanding issues with transitive dependencies.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm building a maven2 open source project, so I'm boned. I can check in the settings file and key off of that during builds, but that's stupid.

This has all just served as an exercise to show me how good gradle really is.